# gcode commands in octoprint: Z moves ignored?

Tags: g-code, octoprint

A while ago, I created some simple command buttons in Octoprint to help with bed levelling, by hopping to particular points on the bed. I realised that what I actually want to do is move Z up 10mm, move, and then home Z though, to avoid ploughing the nozzle along the bed if the level is badly off.

So I did this:

```
  - commands:
    - G91
    - G1 Z-10
    - G90
    - G1 X30 Y160 F9000
    - G28 Z
    name: Back Left
    type: command
```

Which should be, switch to relative move, Move -10mm Z, switch back to absolute, go to the specified point and then home Z.

Except there's no Z move. I get the feeling that something might be optimising the moves together into one, or something similar... how can I get my printer to move up, *then* across, *then* down?

(printer is an quite modified Anet A8 i3 clone - I think the board is Melzi-based?)

Comment: Are you sure that *minus* 10 corresponds to moving the Z axis *up*? Shouldn't that bring the nozzle closer to the printbed instead?

Comment: You know, I could have sworn I tested that separately! You are quite right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I actually want to do is move Z up 10mm

The command `G1 Z-10` tells the printer to *decrease* the Z-axis position, i.e., move the nozzle closer to the bed. You should use `G1 Z10` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks in part to Tom van Der Zanden, I got a working version, which I'll paste below to add some actual value to this question! The G1 XY coordinates for each position are for near the corners on a 220x220 bed, but leaving enough room to access a screw in the corner of the bed if you need to (I don't anymore, but my printer did initially) - for different bed sizes, you'll want to change them. Add to ~/.octoprint/config.yml

```
controls:
- children:
  - commands:
    - M140 S50
    - M104 S190 T0
    name: Preheat
    type: command
  - commands:
    - G91
    - G1 Z10
    - G90
    - G1 X30 Y50 F9000
    - G28 Z0
    name: Front Left
    type: command
  - commands:
    - G91
    - G1 Z10
    - G90
    - G1 X180 Y70 F9000
    - G28 Z0
    name: Front Right
    type: command
  - commands:
    - G91
    - G1 Z10
    - G90
    - G1 X30 Y160 F9000
    - G28 Z0
    name: Back Left
    type: command
  - commands:
    - G91
    - G1 Z10
    - G90
    - G1 X180 Y160 F9000
    - G28 Z0
    name: Back Right
    type: command
  - commands:
    - G91
    - G1 Z10
    - G90
    - G1 X100 Y100 F9000
    - G28 Z0
    name: Centre
    type: command
  layout: horizontal
  name: Levelling
```

[image]